# subtract two dates in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have dates in *ISO Date format*, How can I calculate difference between two dates and also handle null values in *elasticsearch*

Example:

```
date1 ="2013-04-24 10:55:55"

date2 = "2013-05-14 10:55:55"

result_in_seconds = date1? date1-date2 : date2 - date2
```

Comment: It isn't clear what the you are trying to do here? Perhaps you are want a function field in the return results? Or you are trying to query on dates that only differ by a certain number of seconds?

Comment: No I just wanna subtract date fields but using elasticsearch

Comment: Sorry, that still isn't making much sense. Elasticsearch is a search engine that can be used to do date range queries or and can subtract two date values in a doc via script fields. But it doesn't sound like you want to do either.

Comment: curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/db.index/_search/?pretty=true" -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query": "123456","fields": ["id"]}},"script_fields": {"test1": {"script":"new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\").parse(\"2013-04-24 10:55:55\") - new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\").parse(\"2013-04-24 10:55:54\")" }}}} '